# How to add numeric value from one column to other List colum elements in Polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

Suppose I have the following Polars DataFame:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'lst': [[0, 1], [9, 8]],
    'val': [3, 4]
})
```

And I want to add the number in the `val` column, to every element in the corresponding list in the `lst` column, to get the following result:

```
┌───────────┬─────┐
│ lst       ┆ val │
│ ---       ┆ --- │
│ list[i64] ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════╪═════╡
│ [3, 4]    ┆ 3   │
│ [13, 12]  ┆ 4   │
└───────────┴─────┘
```

I know how to add a constant value, e.g.:

```
new_df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col('lst').list.eval(pl.element() + 2)
)
```

But when I try:

```
new_df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col('lst').list.eval(pl.element() + pl.col('val'))
)
```

I get the following error:

```
polars.exceptions.ComputeError: named columns are not allowed in `list.eval`; consider using `element` or `col("")`
```

Is there any elegant way to achieve my goal (**without map_elements**)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `lst` has a fixed number of items for the whole column AND you know how many in advance then you can do this:

```
df.with_columns(
    pl.concat_list(pl.col('lst').list.get(x) + pl.col('val') for x in range(2))
)
```

If not, then you can still do this:

```
df.with_columns(
    pl.concat_list(
        pl.col('lst').list.get(x) + pl.col('val') 
        for x in range(df['lst'].list.len().max())
        )
    .list.gather(
        pl.int_ranges(0,pl.col('lst').list.len())
    )
)
```

The way this works is that it replaces the `2` from the first case with `df['lst'].list.len().max()` which is the longest list in the whole column. Then it does a `gather` so that it only takes the first `n` elements that correspond to the length of each particular `lst`.

`concat_list` isn't super efficient so it **might** be the case that `explode`, `group_by` is more efficient.

```
(df
 .with_row_index('i')
 .explode('lst')
 .group_by('i',maintain_order=True)
 .agg(
     pl.col('lst')+pl.col('val'),
     pl.col('val').first(),
     )
 .drop('i')
)
```

Comment: Since they all have the same length, your first answer made the trick. I wonder if I should right plugin for that - it's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

It has been requested several times, but there doesn't appear to have been much progress:

- https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10918

Polars does "broadcast" arithmetic on structs:

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col("lst").list.to_struct() + pl.struct("val"))
```

```py
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────┬─────┐
│ lst       ┆ val │
│ ---       ┆ --- │
│ struct[2] ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════╪═════╡
│ {3,4}     ┆ 3   │
│ {13,12}   ┆ 4   │
└───────────┴─────┘
```

- **note:** [`.to_struct(n_field_strategy="max_width")`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.to_struct.html#polars.Expr.list.to_struct) is needed if the lists are of different lengths

Depending on what you want to do next - it may be a suitable approach.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder what solution is more efficient

Answer (score 1):

Couple of more possibilities.
First, you can use [`over()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.over.html) expression to [`explode()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.explode.html), calculate and then [`implode()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.implode) to list:

```py
(df
     .with_row_index('i')
     .with_columns(
        (pl.col('lst').explode() + pl.col('val')).implode().over('i')
     ).drop('i')
)

┌───────────┬─────┐
│ lst       ┆ val │
│ ---       ┆ --- │
│ list[i64] ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════╪═════╡
│ [3, 4]    ┆ 3   │
│ [13, 12]  ┆ 4   │
└───────────┴─────┘
```

or you can use [`duckdb`](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/overview.html), with [`unnest()`](https://duckdb.org/docs/archive/0.9.2/sql/query_syntax/unnest) and then aggregate back to [`list()`](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/aggregates.html):

```py
import duckdb

duckdb.sql("""
    select
        a.val,
        (select list(l.e + a.val) from unnest(lst) as l(e)) as lst
    from df as a
""").pl()

┌─────┬───────────┐
│ val ┆ lst       │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ 3   ┆ [3, 4]    │
│ 4   ┆ [13, 12]  │
└─────┴───────────┘
```